# volume vs amount

Tags: bid-ask

Which version is right:

**Version 1:**

```
Amount = Volume x Price per asset
```

**Version 2:**

```
Volume = Amount x Price per asset
```

I guess, version 2. But I am not sure..

When looking at an orderbook, the word `amount` is used. For example:

```
ASK-Price: 1$
ASK-Amount: 4
```

This means that there is an interest to **sell 4 units of the asset with a price of 1$ per asset**. So the `volume` for this is `4x1`. It does NOT mean, that the ASK-amount of 4 is calculated by `Volume * Ask-Price`. That means, **amount must be the number of assets**.

**What is the right distinction between the word `amount` and `volume` in terms of the market?**

Answer (score 3):

Neither is right, because both refer to a number of shares. "Volume" means the number of shares traded in a period (at various prices), "Amount" on an order book refers to the number of shares that the order wants to buy/sell.

I would not be surprised to see "volume" used in an order book, but I would not expect to see "amount" when talking about aggregate trading volume.

Comment: So I should say "I will sell an *amount* of 4 shares" and not "I will sell a *volume* of 4 shares". Right?

Comment: There are orderbooks which uses the word "amount" referring to the number of units. Or?

Comment: But **which word** is the right for the calculation result of `Amount x Price per asset = ???`?

Comment: @nimo23 I've seen "size" most often, but I don't look at order books that closely. IT depends on the context what the right word for "amount * price" would be. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you writing a paper, or software, or something else?

Comment: I want to learn..I am little confused how *amount* and *volume* are used as if they are synonyms..

Comment: The volume you are referring could be also called **turnover** if the volume corresponds to the **market-volume** and not to the volume one client holds, or?

Comment: Because they _are_ synonyms. Finance is full of different words that mean the same thing, and the same word that means different things depending on the context.